# linking tables cakephp

Tags: database, validation, cakephp, models

Hi all I finally got my validation for my invoices model working 100% but now its thrown off my validation in relationship model(which was working) because now it references everything in the wrong table.

The relationship model is supposed to make sure that a user exists in the users table before you can send them a request.

The invoice model is supposed to make sure that a user has a column with another user in the the relationship table.

how can I change it to make it work properly? At the moment the code completely throws off my entire relationship side of the website.

-relationship model

```
class Relationship extends AppModel
{

    var $name = 'Relationship';
    public $useTable = 'relationships_users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Invoice' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Invoice',
                'joinTable'              => 'invoice',
                'foreignKey'             => 'invoice_id'));
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' =>array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' =>'partyone','partytwo',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'username',
            )); 

    var $validate = array(
        'date' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'datevalidation',
                'systemDate'
            ),
            'message' => 'Current Date and System Date is mismatched'
        ),
        'partytwo' => array(
            'userExists' => array(
                'rule' => array(
                    'userExists',
                ),
                'message' => 'That username doesnt exist.'
            ),
        ),
    );

    function datevalidation($field = array(), $compare_field = null)
    {
        if ($field['date'] > $compare_field)
            return TRUE;
        else
            return FALSE;
    }

    function userExists($check)
    {   
        $userExists = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions' => array('User.username'=>$check)));
        if ($userExists == 1) {
           return TRUE;
        }
        else
            return FALSE;
    }
```

-user model

```
   <?php
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

    class User extends AppModel{ 
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Relationship' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'Relationship',
                'joinTable'              => 'relationships_users',
                'foreignKey'             => 'id',
                'unique'                 => false,));


    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $validate = array(
        'username'=>array(
            'The username must be between 5 and 15 characters.'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('between', 5, 15),
                'message'=>'The username must be between 5 and 15 characters.'
            ),
            'That username has already been taken'=>array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'That username has already been taken.'
            )),
        'email'=>array(
            'Valid email'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('email'),
                'message'=>'Please enter a valid email address'
            )
        ),
        'password'=>array(
            'Not Empty'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please enter your password'
                )
            ),
            'Match passwords'=>array(
            'rule'=>'matchPasswords',
            'message'=>'Your passwords do not match'
            )
            ,
            'password_confirmation'=>array(
            'Not Empty'=>array(
                'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Please confirm your password'
            )));


    public function matchPasswords($data){
        if ($data['password']==$this->data['User']['password_confirmation']){
        return true;
        }
        $this->invalidate('password_confirmation','Your passwords do not match');
        return false;
    }

    public function beforeSave(){

    if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        }
        return true;
    }


    }
    ?>
```

invoice model-

```
class Invoice extends AppModel{ 
        var $name='Invoice'; 
        //public $useTable = 'invoices';
        //public $primaryKey = 'id';
        public $belongsTo = array(
        'Relationship' =>array(
            'className' => 'Relationship',
            'foreignKey' =>'relationship_id',
            )
        ); 
        var $validate = array(
            'to' => array(
                'relationshipExists' => array(
                    'rule' => array(
                        'relationshipExists',
                        ),
                    'message' => 'sorry you dont have a relationship with that user.'
                    ),
                ),          
            );

            var $validateTwo = array(
            'datecreated'=>array(
                'dateHasntExpired' => array(
                    'rule'=>array(
                        'dateHasntExpired',
                        ),
                    'message'=> 'sorry but your relationship has expired.'
                    ),
                ),
            );

        public function relationshipExists($check){ 

        $relationshipExists=$this->Relationship->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
            'Relationship.partyone <>' => current($check),
            'Relationship.partytwo' => current($check),
        //  'Relationship.active'==true,
            // get the value from the passed var
  )
));
                if ($relationshipExists == true) {
                    return TRUE;
                    }
                else
                    return FALSE;
                    }
        public function dateHasntExpired($check){   
            $dateHasntExpired=$this->Relationship->find('count', array(
            'conditions'=>array(
            'DATE(Relationship.expirydate) > DATE(Invoice.datecreated)',
                )));
                    if ($dateHasntExpired == true) {
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                        return FALSE;
                    }



    }
```

here is the error that comes up when trying to view current relationship requests

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Invoice.invoice_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Invoice`.`id`, `Invoice`.`to`, `Invoice`.`biller`, `Invoice`.`subject`, `Invoice`.`description`, `Invoice`.`amount`, `Invoice`.`datecreated`, `Invoice`.`duedate`, `Invoice`.`invoice_id` FROM `pra_cake`.`invoices` AS `Invoice` WHERE `Invoice`.`invoice_id` IN (97, 98, 99, 101, 104, 105)

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
```

app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

and here is the error i get when trying to view the relationship requests ive sent

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Invoice.invoice_id' in 'field list'

SQL Query: SELECT `Invoice`.`id`, `Invoice`.`to`, `Invoice`.`biller`, `Invoice`.`subject`, `Invoice`.`description`, `Invoice`.`amount`, `Invoice`.`datecreated`, `Invoice`.`duedate`, `Invoice`.`invoice_id` FROM `pra_cake`.`invoices` AS `Invoice` WHERE `Invoice`.`invoice_id` IN (97, 98, 99, 101, 104, 105)

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp
```

Comment: Please don't use things like "Please help" in your subject line. It takes up space that could be used for writing a better subject, and it makes it harder for people to spot your question. It won't get you help any faster, and it's annoying, plus it wastes the time of people who have to edit your question to remove it that they could be spending trying to answer questions and help people. Thanks. :-)

Comment: needed to use the unbind method in my controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to use the unbind method in my controllers, here is an example of the unbind method I used throughout my relationship controller.

```
public function approve($id=null){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Relationships');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');   
        $this->layout='home_layout';
        $this->Relationship->unbindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Invoice')));
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Relationship->read(NULL, $id);

        } else {
        //sets active to 1
         $this->Relationship->read(null, $id);
         $this->Relationship->set(array('active' => true,));
        if ($this->Relationship->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'request'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
        }
    }
```

and because this threw errors in my invoice controller I used unbind there as well and here is an example of the unbind I used in invoicescontroller

```
 public function viewInvoice($id = NULL){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'View invoice');
        $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
        $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.jpg');
        $this->Invoice->unbindModel(array('belongsTo'=>array('Relationship')));     
        $this->set('invoice', $this->Invoice->read(NULL, $id));
}
```

Comment: is the answer i provided better?